# HTML tags are getting converted

Tags: java, html, xml, oracle-ebs, oracle-xml-publisher

I have the following code snippet to have output  from XML data which is stored in the database table

```
ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
String contentDisposition = "attachment;filename=Test.HTML";
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",contentDisposition);
response.setContentType("text/html");

XMLNode xmlNode = (XMLNode)am.invokeMethod("getDataXML");
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = 
new ByteArrayOutputStream();
xmlNode.print(outputStream);

ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = 
new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

ByteArrayOutputStream pdfFile = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

TemplateHelper.processTemplate(((OADBTransactionImpl)pageContext.getApplicationModule(webBean).getOADBTransaction()).getAppsContext(), 
   "INV", 
   "MyTemplate", 
   ((OADBTransactionImpl)pageContext.getApplicationModule(webBean).getOADBTransaction()).getUserLocale().getLanguage(), 
   ((OADBTransactionImpl)pageContext.getApplicationModule(webBean).getOADBTransaction()).getUserLocale().getCountry(), 
   inputStream, 
   TemplateHelper.OUTPUT_TYPE_HTML, 
   null, pdfFile);


byte[] b = pdfFile.toByteArray();
response.setContentLength(b.length);
os.write(b, 0, b.length);
os.flush();
os.close();
pdfFile.flush();
pdfFile.close();


public XMLNode getDataXML() {
OAViewObject vo = (OAViewObject)findViewObject("DataVO");
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XMLNode xmlNode = 
(XMLNode)vo.writeXML(4, XMLInterface.XML_OPT_ALL_ROWS);
return xmlNode;

}
```

I have HTML tags which is stored in the table as

```
<STRONG>this</STRONG> is only a test.
```

However the above is getting converted to

```
 &lt;STRONG&gt;this&lt;/STRONG&gt;is only a test.
```

How can I preserve the original HTML tags when I execute the code or how do I convert it back to the original without using any third party libraries as we have a restriction of using third party libraries in the server.

Comment: maybe its your unicode

Comment: I don't see how the code you posted is relevant: it justs sends 0 byte to the response. What is your real code?

Comment: We have no idea what all those methods do. The probal is probably in the code of processTemplate.

Comment: @JBNizet `TemplateHelper.processTemplate` is an Oracle EBS method to generate XML publisher report. From the code snippet is there any way I could convert to the original HTML tags? Thanks

Comment: @JBNizet I have posted another question relation to this, kindly have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40816016/599528

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this for more information

> The HTML character encoder converts all applicable characters to their
>   corresponding HTML entities. Certain characters have special
>   significance in HTML and should be converted to their correct HTML
>   entities to preserve their meanings. For example, it is not possible
>   to use the < character as it is used in the HTML syntax to create and
>   close tags. It must be converted to its corresponding < HTML entity
>   to be displayed in the content of an HTML page. HTML entity names are
>   case sensitive.

and then this may help you :

use the Apache Commons `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()` for this:

> Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing
>   the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes. Supports
>   HTML 4.0 entities.

**Edit**

it seems the java itself has this method

```
URLDecoder.decode(String stringToDecode)
```

and this

```
URLDecoder.decode(String stringToDecode, String charset);
```

hope this works for you