# Incompatible types; found: class java.lang.String, required: class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, bytearrayoutputstream

This is a continuation of [HTML tags are getting converted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815286/html-tags-are-getting-converted)

When I try to the following

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 stream= stream.toString().replaceAll("&lt;","<");
```

I am getting

> incompatible types; found: class java.lang.String, required: class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

How can I replace `&lt;` with `<`

As mentioned in the other question, my HTML tags are getting converted and due to this reason before I print to open the HTML page, I would like to convert < to < if it exist in the stream.

Kindly suggest the reason for down voting as it makes sense rather than down voting for the sake of it.

Comment: I think the downvoter's reason is that you haven't given enough context of what you're planning on doing with this string. `replaceAll("&lt;","<")` will indeed do the replacement you want...

Comment: @qxz Yes, point noted and accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign the result of `replaceAll` (a `String`) to `stream`, a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. I think you mean to just create a new variable of type `String`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String str = stream.toString().replaceAll("&lt;","<");
```

You can then convert the `String` to a byte array, using [`getBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()):

```
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
```

Comment: With this how I can I change the values in the stream instance of ByteArrayOutputStream? Idea is to replace values in stream instance.

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant, how do I assign bytes to stream because what I intend to convert is a small part of the value or data exists in stream instance as it contains a lot of XML code. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815286/html-tags-are-getting-converted) as this is a continuation.

Comment: You can't change the contents of the stream (except for writing to the end, of course). At what point do you want the HTML converted? How are you intending on eventually using this stream/byte array?

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, my HTML tags are getting converted and due to this reason before I print to open the HTML page, I would like to convert `&lt;` to `<` if it exist in the stream. Thanks

Comment: You should add the surrounding code in your question, including how/when you send the HTML. Then I'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129098/discussion-between-user75ponic-and-qxz).

Comment: I am using string replaceAll method and using StringWriter to write all the converted string to have output in HTML format. Thanks